# Copy div content to another div content using C# code-behind

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms, innerhtml

I want to use C# to copy the content from div1 to div2. I used `div1.innerHTML` but I'm getting error with not being literal.

```
<div runat="server" id="div1"> 
    Number: <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtNumber^!" /> 
    Site: <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtNumber^!" /> 
</div> 
<div runat="server" id="div2" />
```

**C# code :**

I want to replace the ids and then copy to another div

```
for (i=1; i<3; i++) { for (j=1; j<3; j++) 
{ 
    div2.innerHTML = div1.innerHTML.replace("^",i).replace("!",j); 
}
```

Comment: Can u post the code what you have tried with the exact error message.

Comment: divUnit1.InnerHtml = divUnit.InnerHtml;

Comment: Cannot get inner content of divUnit because the contents are not literal.

Comment: Here is the ASP.NET code. I want to use C# to copy the content from div1 to div2, by replacing i and j from IDs.
    
    ASP.NET code --- I want to replace the ids and then copy to another div

Comment: <div runat="server" id="div1">
        Number: <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtNumber^!" />
        Site: <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtNumber^!"  />
    </div>
    
    <div runat="server" id="div2" />
        
    C# code : --- I want to replace the ids and then copy to another div
    
    for (i=1; i<3; i++)
    {
        for (j=1; j<3; j++)
        {
            div2.innerHTML = div1.innerHTML.replace("^",i).replace("!",j);
        }
    }

Comment: Any idea ? Getting stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that. Because you want to copy textboxes. This is impossible. If you want to change Textbox's id, just type Textbox.Id = "your_value"

Comment: Can you please provide me basic code (html) for copying div values to another div ? I tried many ways and running out of ideas ?